# Error when importing tensorflow in Python 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, python-3.8

I am using

- Python 3.8.7
- pip 20.2.3
- Windows 10 64bit
- CPU Intel Pentium G4400

and when I `import tensorflow as tf` on the Python IDLE ( that comes with Python when installing it ) , it shows the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: 動態連結程式庫 (DLL) 初始化例行程序失敗。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python__MyFinalProject__ML\TensorFlow.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: 動態連結程式庫 (DLL) 初始化例行程序失敗。


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

I tried download the VS and included the C++ package in the VS installer. But still can’t fix this problem : (

Can anyone please help

And I'm sorry that there are some traditional Chinese characters and I google translate it : "動態連結程式庫 (DLL) 初始化例行程序失敗。" --> "The dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."

## Edit

Just came up with a solution : is that my PC's CPU is too old that some `instructions` ( e.g. AVX support ) required by `tensorflow` are missing.

I've tried to find a work-around like `intel sde`. But I would like to suggest that , don't waste time on that , just replace a new CPU or buy a new PC. Save your time !  : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to simply install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable 64 bits](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840). This way, the DLL is installed in system32 folder and the [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512) can be rectified.

Comment: so i need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable 64bits although i have already installed the Visual Studio 2019 ?

Comment: is your processor AVX Supported ?

Comment: um , idk : ( how can i check that ?

Comment: `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0` try this

Comment: `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512`

Comment: this page has 5-6 solutions. try them

Comment: i try this `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0` but raise error : (
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0`

Comment: and i found that i m using  intel(R) Pentium(R) G4400

Comment: i tried , but still cant fix : ((( can anyone help ....?

Comment: just found that my PC's CPU is too old that some `instruction` required are missing ( my old PC's CPU : `intel Pentium G4400` ). I just buy a new PC and it works fine ( `import tensorflow` ) without creating `venv`. Reply to @Ajay , your answer should work and I can also make use of the `venv` when needed. thanks a lot for the solution and links : )